# Deleting data of rows selected from object?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, delete-row

I am not able to clear data from object , after I delete it from the grid. here's : http://plnkr.co/edit/u1HmCwsEzVrgQJ2SLUgY?p=preview

I am using this to delete rows from grid.

```
angular.forEach($scope.mysel, function(rowItem) { 
  $scope.myData.splice($scope.myData.indexOf(rowItem), 1);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Issue 1:**

You need to empty the original `$scope.mysel` array instead of removing it:

```
while ($scope.mysel.length > 0) {
  $scope.mysel.pop();
}
```

**Issue 2:**

*Code example changed during answering, so not sure there originally was a second issue.*

For clarity's sake, don't modify the array that is being iterated until the iteration has completed:

```
$scope.removeRow = function() {

  angular.forEach($scope.mysel, function(rowItem) {
    $scope.myData.splice($scope.myData.indexOf(rowItem), 1);
  });

  while ($scope.mysel.length > 0) {
    $scope.mysel.pop();
  }
};
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/qEaoxL02uz5yqvw2sJ3E?p=preview

Comment: That worked, what i am not clear with is, what you said about forEach ? can you please explain, if you can ?

Comment: I think you modified your Plunker code example while I was answering, perhaps to test the other answer, so it might be that what I mentioned in Issue 2 was not originally an issue for you. As long as you don't modify the array you are iterating during the actual iteration, forEach will work as well: http://plnkr.co/edit/okCOa5bl1XXQ0Fkv9PXS?p=preview

Comment: You're welcome :) Updated answer to reflect the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like deleting reference removes the relationship between the grid selection and the `mysel` reference. And you are creating a new array for it as well,
works when you do like this,

```
$scope.removeRow = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.mysel, function(rowItem) { 
    $scope.myData.splice($scope.myData.indexOf(rowItem),1);

   while($scope.mysel.length > 0) {
      $scope.mysel.pop();
   }

});
```

Comment: this has a probelem, this is not deleting all selected rows but only last

Comment: Yeah , you need to remove them all ,just like @tasseKATT answer